# Not able to search python package pmock using pip

Tags: python, pip, pmock

I'm trying to install python package [pmock](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pmock/). 
Using following command:

```
sudo pip install pmock
```

However, I'm getting following error:

```
Collecting pmock
  Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/pmock/

  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pmock (from versions: )
  Some externally hosted files were ignored as access to them may be unreliable (use --allow-external pmock to allow).
Cleaning up...
No matching distribution found for pmock
```

What is the correct way to install python package using `pip`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the common issues coming via pip installtions, generally django setup also throws this error when setting up environment via `requirements.txt`.Basic solution is to allow *external* and *unverified* option too

try external hosted files this way :

```
sudo pip install pmock --allow-external pmock --allow-unverified pmock
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped. :)